# Django OneToOneField with Users.Id

Tags: django

I'd like to use the OneToOneField model field, with the user ID as the foreign key.  For example:

```
owner_id = models.OneToOneField("User.id")
```

But, I get this error:

```
'owner_id' has a relation with model User.id, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

I've also tried with Users.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't put in the `User.id` (since `User.id` is *not* a model) but simply supply the `User` model.

```
class ToySoldier(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and Django will handle the rest itself.

Comment: Thanks!  Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
owner_id = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

here is an 
 [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)